# iTextSharp Footer Gets Progressively Bolder with Each Page

Tags: java, itext, footer

Using `OnEndPage`, I add a footer to my PDF created with `iTextSharp`. The footer font gets progressively bolder with each page.

How can I create consistent NORMAL fonts in my footer?

Here is my code:

```
 public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image gif = null;

        if (FooterImage)
        {

            if (File.Exists(PathImages))
            {
                gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(PathImages);
                gif.ScaleToFit(75f, 75f);
                gif.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

            }

        }
        string sFooter = string.Empty;
        if (FooterURL != null && FooterURL.Length > 0)
        {
            sFooter = FooterURL + "                    ";
        }

        if (FooterDate != null && FooterDate.Length > 0)
        {
            sFooter += FooterDate + "                    ";
        }
        if (FooterPage)
        {
            sFooter += "Page " + doc.PageNumber.ToString();
        }

        PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
        footerTbl.TotalWidth = 900;
        footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        Phrase ph = new Phrase(sFooter, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(ph);

        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.PaddingLeft = 10;

        footerTbl.AddCell(cell);

        if (FooterImage)
        {
            PdfContentByte cbfoot = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfTemplate tpl = cbfoot.CreateTemplate(gif.Width / 5, gif.Height / 5);
            tpl.AddImage(gif);
            cbfoot.AddTemplate(tpl, doc.PageSize.Width - 100, 10);
        }

        footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, 30, writer.DirectContent);

    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the page events object? And could you share a result PDF file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old days, when there wasn't as much choice as today regarding fonts, people used workarounds to create bold fonts. One way to make a font bold, was by adding the same text over and over again at the same position. I think that this is happening to you.

When you use page events correctly, the `onEndPage()` method is triggered **automatically** each time a page ends. My guess is that you're doing something very wrong that triggers the `onEndPage()` many times. Maybe you are called the `onEndPage()` from your code, maybe you're adding the page event to the writer more than once (and page events are cumulative).

If I have to guess, I would guess that you are doing the latter. My guess is based on the fact that you are using variables such as `FooterImage` in your `onEndPage()` method. How are you setting that variable. If you are setting it in the constructor of the page event and you're adding the new page event over and over again to the writer, then you're doing it wrong.